# Comparing stability of phases under constant pressure

Tags: density-functional-theory, thermodynamics

I have used DFT to calculate the internal energy of a couple of different phases at 0K. As I would also like to compare the relative stability of the phases at finite temperature, I have also computed the phonon spectrum for each phase using phonopy (http://phonopy.github.io/phonopy/).

Phonopy also calculates thermal properties related to the phonon spectrum, namely the harmonic phonon energy as well as the partition function Z, and writes out the quantities: Helmholtz free energy F, entropy S, and the constant volume heat capacity Cv. I have seen in the literature comparisons of the relative stability of different phases using the Enthalpy.

Is this a fair thing to do so here and what is a good way to do so?

I do realize that the enthalpy differential can be written as dH = TdS - P dV. I don't have any data on the volume change with temperature, but if I assume P is small then dH = T dS. Would it be fair to integrate the change in H from 0K to a temperature T by expressing the Enthalpy as $$U(0K) + \int_{0}^{T} {T dS}$$ or is there a more appropriate way to go about computing the enthalpy (for solids). Note both phases are ordered so the mixing entropy is negligible.

Comment: +1 The enthalpy is the relevant thermodynamic potential when you have a fixed external pressure. So you should compare the enthalpy of different structures when you want to determine their relative stability as a function of pressure. Most DFT codes will allow you to impose an external pressure (stress tensor) and give you the resultant enthalpy.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question?  Was the comment by @ProfM helpful?